# Cloudant Query: Access data in nested array AND sort by if-statement

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, cloudant

I have a question pertaining to how to query in cloudant with (1) a nested array and (2) sort by using an if-statement. I have been to the following websites, but I still need assistance.

https://docs.cloudant.com/guides/cloudant-query.html

https://docs.cloudant.com/api/cloudant-query.html

I want to return the documents that meet satisfy the following pseudo code:

**if event[i].type == "check_in" then sort by event[i].time**

Here is a snippet of the JSON data structure that I am using.

```html
{
      "status" : "active",
      "event": [
        {
          "type": "check_in",
          "time": "11/19/2014 15:34:12"
        },
        {
          "type": "check_out",
          "time": "11/20/2014 17:54:22"
        }
      ]
}
```

Here are some questions I have that may break this problem down:

(1) How can I access event[0].type data?

(2) How can I loop through the entire event array inside of a Cloudant Query and check if event[i] == "check_in" for each object in the event array?

(3) How can I sort on the timestamp data (assume it is an integer for simplicity)?

(4) What format does the timestamp have to be in for me to sort it in a Cloudant Query?

Could you help point me in the right direction to help accomplish this? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: "11/19/2014 15:34:12" is a string, so you will not get the expected results after the sort always. For example, "3/19/2014 .. " would come after the former in an ascending order sort. What if the event type of check in does not exist? For those documents what should be the criteria?

Comment: Thank for the comment BatScream. For the moment, ignore the sorting criteria. We can revisit that topic after I have the proper documents returned. In my case, if a JSON data structure has a "status" = "active", then there will always be "type" = "check_in". Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant Query doesn't seem to work with indexing array elements and query against. 
You can create a View to get the same result by indexing each array elements and then query on the View.